# Use property file's property in spring mvc configuration servlet xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties

I use following line of code to read `config.properties` file in my spring mvc configuration servlet xml file.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///${config.properties}" />
```

`config.properties` contains a property say: **propertyName = propertyValue**

I want to use this **propertyName's value** in spring mvc configuration servlet xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of configuring as pool with properties taken from a properties file

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="300000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="6" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="75" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="75" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="100" />
</bean>
```

The property file contains there rows

```
database.url=localhost:1521:xe
database.username=dbusername
database.password=dbpassword
```

Comment: How can I use this to call `props.properties` inside `src/main/resources` to do file I/O in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///${config.properties}" />
```

to your servlet.xml file.