# Update the default locale value by using properties file in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My plan is to update the default locale value in servlet-context.xml with the value of messages.properties file. Verified the other StackOverflow questions and other links as well, but not the success.

servlet-context.xml is,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="C:\\Users\\Mahesh\\Downloads\\SpringInternalization\\src\\main\\resources\\messages.properties" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <!-- <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> -->
    <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" >
    <value>${property.language}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

 <!-- 
 <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jocata.spring" />
```

Please help on this guys. Thanks in advance. 
Tried the following,

[Use property file's property in spring mvc configuration servlet xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253272/use-property-files-property-in-spring-mvc-configuration-servlet-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your language file names?
Why do you need to specify the absolute path of your properties file?

Try this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:messages.properties" />
```

OR use forward slash in your file path

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:C:/Users/Mahesh/Downloads/SpringInternalization/src/main/resources/messages.properties" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rocherlee